# How to stop input in this code- a code to input an 1D array with unknown size

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, vector, input

I try to do this but i don't know  how to stop input. I build a code with input an array with integer element, when input element not integer, it will ignore. So i can't stop it.

```
do {
  if(std::cin >> val) {
    if(val == 0) break;
    vec.push_back(val);
  } else { 
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.ignore(1,'\n');
  }
} while(true);
```

I try to enter ctrl + x,z,d but it don't work.

Comment: *..it will ignore. So i can't stop it.* Then why ignore, just break.

Comment: `if(val == 0) break;`  the loop stops when you enter `0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can decide to stop input on end of file. The condition is raised on actual end of file when you read from a true file, or but using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Z</kbd>  or <kbd>F6</kbd> on Windows or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd> on Linux. You just have to test for it before ignoring any offending input:

```
do {
  if(std::cin >> val) {
    if(val == 0) break;
    vec.push_back(val);
  } else if (std::cin.eof()) {
    break;       // exit loop on eof
  } else { 
    std::cin.clear();        // ignore any offending input up to end of line
    std::cin.ignore(1,'\n');
  }
} while(true);
```